# Rolling stock distribution in R

Tags: r, dplyr, statistics

I've got a data frame containing stock on hand by month, number of arriving goods and expected consumption.

I need to calculate the number i need to buy each month to maintain my stock above certain safety stock each month.

For example: I have 3 units on stock, 4 arriving the first month, expected consumption of 0. therefore i don't need to buy any units this month and i'm left with 3+4-0=7.

That means next month I'll start with 7, say consumption will be 7 and arriving 1 unit. therefore I'll fall short on 3 below my safety stock of 4 so I need to program a purchase of 3 units that month.

Month 3 I start with my 4 units of the safety stock, 1 unit arriving, consumption 5 so I'm at 0, so I need to program to purchase 4 to replenish my safety stock.

As an example i need to replicate the following where "to purchase" is what i need to calculate

```
df <- data.frame(type = c("a","a","a","a","a"),
date = as.Date(c("2020-01-01", "2020-02-01", "2020-03-01", "2020-04-01", "2020-05-01")),
stock= c(3,0,0,0,0),
arriving = c(4,1,1,3,2),
consumption = c(0,7,5,5,3),
safety_stock = c(4,4,4,4,4),
to_purchase= c(0,3,4,2,1))
```

Comment: If you start that next month with 7, I think your `df$stock[2]` should be 7, not 0. It's the initial units of stock that you begin with on that month. Thus, your `stock` values should be `df$stock = c(3, 7, 4, 4, 4)` to reflect your units of stock that you will begin with each month. The last three values are "4" because they are the remaining stocks (from safety stocks) carried over from last month.

Comment: Exactly, but im stanging in month 1, so those stocks from month 2 ahead need to also be calculated based on the leftover stock while also ensuring the safety stock, as pointed out in another answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming these stocks are non-perishable, then the initial `stock` for each month should equal to the amount you have left from the previous month.

Your `to_purchase` equation for each month should be 
`to_purchase = safety_stock - (stock - consumption + arriving)`, 
which is basically demand minus available supply.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  type = c("a","a","a","a","a"),
  date = as.Date(c("2020-01-01", "2020-02-01", "2020-03-01", "2020-04-01", "2020-05-01")),
  stock = c(3,7,4,4,4),
  arriving = c(4,1,1,3,2),
  consumption = c(0,7,5,5,3),
  safety_stock = c(4,4,4,4,4)
) %>% 
  mutate(
    to_purchase = safety_stock - (stock - consumption + arriving), # purchase equation
    to_purchase = ifelse(to_purchase < 0, 0, to_purchase) # if negative, change value to zero
  )
```

However, a problem with this is that, if you are trying to calculate how much you need to buy (`to_purchase`), you will likely also need to calculate how much you have left over from the previous month (`stock`). Thus, your code should include calculations for the initial `stock` of each month, as well.

```
df <- data.frame(
  type = c("a","a","a","a","a"),
  date = as.Date(c("2020-01-01", "2020-02-01", "2020-03-01", "2020-04-01", "2020-05-01")),
  stock = c(3,NA,NA,NA,NA),
  arriving = c(4,1,1,3,2),
  consumption = c(0,7,5,5,3),
  safety_stock = c(4,4,4,4,4),
  to_purchase = NA
) 

for(i in 2:nrow(df)){
  # determine if you need to purchase anything from the previous month
  h = i-1
  df$to_purchase[h] = df$safety_stock[h] - (df$stock[h] - df$consumption[h] + df$arriving[h])
  df$to_purchase[h] = ifelse(df$to_purchase[h] < 0, 0, df$to_purchase[h])
  # determine initial stock of the current month
  df$stock[i] = df$stock[h] + df$arriving[h] - df$consumption[h] + df$to_purchase[h]
  # determine if you need to purchase anything for the current month
  df$to_purchase[i] = df$safety_stock[i] - (df$stock[i] - df$consumption[i] + df$arriving[i])
  df$to_purchase[i] = ifelse(df$to_purchase[i] < 0, 0, df$to_purchase[i])
}

df
#>   type       date stock arriving consumption safety_stock to_purchase
#> 1    a 2020-01-01     3        4           0            4           0
#> 2    a 2020-02-01     7        1           7            4           3
#> 3    a 2020-03-01     4        1           5            4           4
#> 4    a 2020-04-01     4        3           5            4           2
#> 5    a 2020-05-01     4        2           3            4           1
```